# What might be wrong with CMD(windows 10) that its showing this error message when i am entering ipconfig

Tags: cmd

[image]
what it might worng in this code its not taking ipconfig command, does it is because of path settings in environment variable

Comment: See the Image i upload and help me

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/OS tech support.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/335102/why-is-ipconfig-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command ?

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `path` contains a semicolon-separated list of directories which `cmd` scans to find an executable.

You should not change `path` without understanding the consequences. The file `ipconfig.exe` is usually stored in `c:\Windows\System32` and possibly also `c:\Windows\SysWOW64`. At least one of these directories should be included in the list assigned to `path` in order to execute the command.